# PYZMQ - "Resource temporarily unavailable" error when using ioloop and multiprocessing

Tags: python, ipc, multiprocessing, zeromq, pyzmq

I'm using python ZMQ to make two process communicate over ipc.

The idea is to create N process with multiprocessing module. Each process create a zmq context and a PULL socket (IPC type) with a ZMQStream to watch it.

And then the main process send json data to children process.

The problem is that I sometime get the following:
`"Resource temporarily unavailable (signaler.cpp:201)"`.
This is not an exception, I can't catch it.

Does someone use ZMQStream, IOLoop and multiprocessing together ?
Thanks.

Version use of libzmq and python-zmq: 2.1.11-1

Comment: Are you binding with only the master? You can bind with only one socket. The other processes have to connect.

Comment: Yes only the master is binding. I found my problem. I forked after creating the IOLoop, so there where somehow sharing some resources. If I fork before creating the IOLoop everything goes fine.